# Problem concerning the number of 3-digit integers that are both composite and have no prime divisors less than 15

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

How many three-digit composite integers are not divisible by any prime less than $15$?

I guess this could be written as, if $a$ was a 3-digit integer that is prime factorized as:
$a=p_1p_2...p_k$, the prime factors 
$p_1,p_2,...p_k >15$.

Comment: Since the number has three digits k is 1 or 2.

Comment: @Bernd and $k \not = 1$ because it is composite, so $k = 2$

Comment: @JohnLou Thanks - it's a little early. So since k = 2 one factor can be at most about 999/15. So there are left only some possible primes and you ar done combining them.

Comment: I just listed all of the possible combinations, and I got $27$

Comment: Check this link for a list. I don't think I missed any. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bmlkim98ap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p_i >15$ so $p_i\ge 17$

$999/17 =<59$ so $p_i <59$ so $p_i\le 57$

$17^3 >999$ so your $k <3$ and as the number is composite $k\ge 2$.  So $k=2$

So $a=p_1*p_2$ where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are from
 $17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53$

If we assume $p_1\le p_2$ then $p_1 \le p_2 \le \frac {999}{p_1} $.

So if $p_1=17$ there between $17*17$ to $17*53$ there are $10$ acceptable numbers.

$999/19<53$ So between $19*19$ to $19*47$ there are $8$ acceptable numbers.

$999/23\approx 43$ so between $23*23$ to $23*43$ there are $6$ acceptable numbers.

(By the way.  $999/23$ is so very close to $43$ that $23*43=989$ is the largest such number.)

$999/29<35$ so between $29*29$ and $29*31$ there are $2$ acceptable numbers.

$999/31\approx 32$ so $31*31$ is an acceptable number.  And there can't be any with both factors greater than $31$ as $37*37 >999$.

So there are $27$ possible such composites.

Comment: $57$ is not prime $57 = 3*19$

Comment: Your answer should then be $27$

Comment: Well, that was stupid of me.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt {999}<32$, and $\frac  {999}{15}\lt 67$, so $15\lt p_1\le p_2\lt 67$...  Consider all products $17\cdot 17,17\cdot 19, 17\cdot23, 17\cdot 29, 17\cdot 31, 17 \cdot 37$ etc formed by primes up to $61$, without both being over $ 32$

(You can save some time by dividing the first prime into $999$, thus getting a bound on the size of the other one )

Sorry I'm too lazy to finish this list right now. ..
But repeat what was done for  $17$ for the primes up to  $61$...

Comment: Why aren't you consider squares?

Comment: @fleablood I guess I should have started with  ${17}^2$...  you are right. ..

Comment: Your method is good.  I absolutely can not understand the accept answer.  But oddly it got the same number , 28, that I did so it could be weirdly explained.  Or it could be coincidence.

Comment: By the way $15$ isn't prime so we can get our upper limit by $999/17=58.7$ so we don't need any prime over 57.

Comment: @fleablood you are on the ball...  the accepted answer is  incorrect : $171$  ah, I see, the other part comes out right. ..

Comment: If you don't include the 143 primes that answer got 28 which I believe is correct but the reasoning that there are 25 ways of choosing 2 for the primes less than 37 just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: fixed it. Now I have 180.

Comment: @fleablood how about  $2$ of $5$, with replacement

Comment: 2 of 5 with replacement?  I do not understand.

Comment: @fleablood $2$ primes from a list of  $5$, repetition allowed, gives $5^2$

Comment: But order does not matter and the list is 11, not 5..  And you can't pick any two-- the value of the first limits the range of the secind.  That argument is simply wrong, whereas yours and mine, I believe, to be correct.